# How to download azure devops universal artifact using only PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I already know I can use `az` cli to download universal artifacts, but I am wondering if there is a PowerShell way of doing it using Azure PowerShell modules.

```
az artifacts universal publish `
    --organization https://msazure.visualstudio.com/ `
    --project "abc" `
    --scope project `
    --feed "$feed" `
    --name "$app" `
    --version $version `
    --path $path
```

There is also a rest API available but that more to get information about the package and not download/publish package.

```
GET https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/packages?packageNameQuery={packageName}
```

Comment: Does using the command `help Get-AzDeploymentManagerArtifactSource` give anything helpful?

Comment: @lit this for getting azure devops pipeline artifacts, not pushing a package, I think

Comment: In your question title and body you are talking about *downloading*. But your comment is talking about uploading. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @lit, you can use
[`Get-AzDeploymentManagerArtifactSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.deploymentmanager/?view=azps-10.0.0) command to retrieve the artifacts from the storage resources. To run this command, you need to install the `Az DeploymentManager` in the console and import it.

After that, I tried in the below manner and it worked as expected.

```
Get-AzDeploymentManagerArtifactSource -ResourceGroupName "<resourcegroup>" -Name "ArtifactSource"
```

***Output:***

[image]

***Or***

To download universal artifacts using Azure PowerShell, try below script by providing the required parameters such as the feed name, project, artifact files and organization details.

```
$org = "https://xxxx.azure.com/"
$project = "xxx"
$patoken = ""
$artifact = "New"
$version = "0.0.1"
$file= "/pathofthefile"
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$org/$project/_apis/artifact/collections?artifact=$artifact&api-version=6.0-preview.1"
$info = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $patoken"} -Method Get
$Url = $info.value[0].url
$uri = "$Url?artifact=$artifact&version=$version&file=$file&api-version=6.0-preview.1"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $pat"} -Method Get -OutFile $file
```